# invokes a class that contains static getUser () in the future

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a API controller named user_controller.dart

```
static getCompany() async {
    return await Http.get("user/getCompany");
  }
```

how to call `user/getCompany` in future
if this is the code I have

```
       Future<String> loadClient() async{  
          return await
          Http.get('user/getCompany'); 
 }
```

I have tried adding `user / getCompany` in await http.get but it is null or method that has problems

Answer (score -1):

```
  Future<String> getCari({String data}) async {
    print('aa');
    await http.post('${Strings.api}/comm',
        body: {"t": query != '' ? "$query" : ""}).then((res) {
      data = res.body;
    });
    return data;
  }
```

Comment: where is user / getCompany entered?

Comment: @MuratAslan, it's common curtesy to provide an example working for the author's case or at least provide some clarification on your code making it easier for the author to map it to their problem.